# Sink pressure increases after turning water off and on again?

Tags: water, faucet, water-pressure

The water pressure in my kitchen sink is usually low when I first turn it on, but if I turn it off an on again, the water pressure increases. Subsequent attempts to turn it on and off do not alter the pressure, unless I turn it off and let some time pass, at which point the pressure is lower again next time I turn it on. The water pressure seems normal elsewhere in the house.

I've already cleaned the aerator and checked the hot/cold water valves to make sure they're open all the way. This seems odd to me. Any insights on what it might be, and how to fix it?

This is not the exact faucet I have, but it's a similar style:
https://secure.img2-ag.wfcdn.com/im/91148106/resize-h800%5Ecompr-r85/8418/8418965/Pull+Out+Touch+Single+Handle+Kitchen+Faucet.jpg

Comment: Are you on municipal water or do you have a well.  If a well, the symptom sounds like a pressure tank failure.

Comment: Municipal. But thank you,  I just learned something about wells.  :)